# How can I hide the quantity box on the product page if it is a configurable product in Magento 1.7?

Tags: magento

I am working with Magento 1.7. How can I hide the quantity box if the product is a configurable product? If it is a simple or other type of product the quantity box must show. Can anyone assist me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml

Copy it to your local theme and then

```
if($_product->isConfigurable()) { 
    <input type="hidden" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" />      
}
else{
    <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
}
```